# Comparing JSON from service to data-bound value in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Using a Service I am retrieving a JSON Array successfully, I am then pumping that data into my Controller and trying to compare with a data bound value as the user enters what they would like their username to be, but I am not showing a log when the values should match. Here is what I have:

Angular service:

```javascript
loginApp.factory('userData', function($http, $log) {
    return {
        getUsers: function(scb) {
            $http({method: 'GET', url: 'somelink/ajax/current_users.php'}).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $log.info(data, status, headers(), config);
                scb(data);
            }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $log.warn(data, status, headers(), config);
            });

        }
    };
});
```

My Controller:

```javascript
loginApp.controller('loginController',
        function loginController($scope, userData) {

            // If I run a log on the `activeusers` 
            // I get the same console log as below    
            userData.getUsers(function(current_users) {
                $scope.activeusers = current_users;
            });

            $scope.createAccnt = {
                fname: "",
                lname: "",
                username: function(inValue) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.activeusers.length; i++) {
                        if ($scope.activeusers[i].username == inValue) {
                            console.log("Username matches existing!!");
                        }
                    }
                },
                email: ""
            };
}
```

---

JSON Array returned:

```json
[
    {
        "user_id": "1",
        "username": "userone",
        "password": "",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "email": "",
        "active": "",
        "auth_token": ""
    },
    {
        "user_id": "2",
        "username": "usertwo",
        "password": "",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "email": "",
        "active": "",
        "auth_token": ""
    }
]
```

Console shows a status code of 200 and shows all of the data requested, it similar to this:

```
[Object, Object]
> 0
    user_id: "1"
    username: "userone"
    password: ""
    first_name: ""
    last_name: ""
    email: ""
    active: "1"
    auth_token: ""
    __proto__: Object
> 1
    user_id: "2"
    username: "usertwo"
    password: ""
    first_name: ""
    last_name: ""
    email: ""
    active: "1"
    auth_token: ""
    __proto__: Object
```

All of my data binding works perfectly, just the comparison. Is my for loop or my if statement incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if i'm not understanding your question but should

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.createAccount.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.createAccount[i].username == inValue) {
        console.log("Username matches existing!!");
    }
}
```

Really be

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.activeusers .length; i++) {
    if ($scope.activeusers [i].username == inValue) {
        console.log("Username matches existing!!");
    }
}
```

replacing createAccount with activeusers

Comment: Yes it should thank you, my apologies, I fixed that but am still getting no log message on matches.

Comment: It seems like a section of your code is missing. What triggers createAccnt.userName() ?

Comment: That's where my issue is, when I was trying to quickly set up the binds I had put `createAccnt.username()` in the name attribute of the input tag. Now I have it as a value in an `ng-bind` and the console is throwing a "Cannont get value length from an undefined.", I'll look into this. I am going to mark this answer as accepted. Thanks